# How to clear button's color when next button is clicked?

Tags: java, android

How to change button's color to default after next button is clicked? I have this code that sets color to the button in onclicklistener:

```
Button button = (Button) v;
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));
```

I have one click listener for all my buttons. How to clear this botton's background color when the next one is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Either, store the reference to the previous button in the scope of your activity and use it in the onclick to reset it.
Or set background of all buttons, except the one which is clicked.

```
Button previousButton = null;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //reset old button
    if (previousButton != null) {
        previousButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x000000));
    }

    //prettify new button
    Button button = (Button) v;
    button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

    previousButton = button;
}
```

Comment: How to do the first thing?

Comment: Nope, did not work. I placed Button previousButton = null; in scope of the activity, and if I use rest of the code in my onClickListener old buttons never reset, they all get color, and in I use it in onClick(View v) buttons never get colored.

Comment: Your did something wrong somewhere. Have you tried debugging and see the value of previousButton?

Comment: Well, I've copied your code where you said I should. Didn't try debugging.

Comment: Have you changed the first colorfilter? This should be the 'normal' button look. I just guessed a value...

Comment: Yes I did. I does not set any color to my buttons if I use it in overriden onClick. If I use it in my onClickListener it colors my buttons, but never clears them when I click next button. :(

Comment: I've tried even with previousButton.getBackground().clearColorFilter(); but it did not work.