# How to clear color of a button?

Tags: java, android

Not only how to clear color to default color of my button, but also in what moment in my code to do it? I've tried everything but no luck. When I click a button I set some green color with opacity. Now when I click next button the same happens but the first button is still set to green. I need it to revert to original color.
I tried with:

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
```

Here's my code:

```
final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

           private Button buttonClicked;

           public void onClick(View v) {
               Button button = (Button) v;
               button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

               if (buttonClicked == null) {
                   // first button is clicked
                   buttonClicked = button;
                   // only do stuff if buttons are in different layouts
               } else{
           if (!button.getParent ().equals(buttonClicked.getParent())) {
                // second button is clicked

            if(buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag()) ){

               // second button is clicked and same tag but different button

               Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
               buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
               buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
               button.setEnabled(false);
               buttonClicked = null;
               } else {
               //reset LightingColorFilter first
               Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               buttonClicked = null;

               }
              }else{

                  buttonClicked = button;
              }
           }
               }       
           };
```

Comment: Similar question is answered in this post. Please check

[Clear Button Color][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704898/how-to-clear-buttons-color-when-next-button-is-clicked?rq=1

Comment: I saw that and tried, but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a simple program which toggles the light filter on and off.

Here is the Activity:

```
 Button buttonClicked = null;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
     }

     public void clickedButton(View v) {
         Button button = (Button)v;
         button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF,
                                                                       0x66FF33));

         if (buttonClicked != null) {
             buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
         }
         buttonClicked = button;

     }
```

and here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/boss"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
            />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttsky"
            android:layout_below="@id/boss"
            android:onClick="clickedButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="pushMe"
            />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttground"
            android:layout_below="@id/buttsky"
            android:onClick="clickedButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="no, pushMe"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I get error "method getColorFilter is undefined for the type Drawable".

Comment: Shoot, I was pulling from ImageView source and though that would work.  I'll look at it more closely.

Comment: Main problem here is that I don't know where exactly to place the code for clearing the first clicked button on second click.

Comment: Have you thought about just keeping around an activity variable (Button previousButton = null;) that starts as null then stores the address of the clicked button, then when you hit the method again, you check previousButton, and if its not null, you reset its color filter?

Comment: I actually did try that, but that's out of scope of my knowledge. :))) Can you help me out to wrap this thing up?

Comment: I can try to help, but I won't be able to for a while, as I"m heading to work.

Comment: OK, when you get some time. Just don't forget me. :))

Comment: You forgot me, didn't you? :(((

Comment: Nope. :) Let me check it out.

Comment: I have tried your little program and it does not work. When I press first button it gets white colored, but when I press the second one, the first is still white, they are both white.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28167/discussion-between-halr-and-marjanbaz)

Comment: I didn't see you are here. Let me know when you are available to go on chat.

Comment: This code of yours clears all clicked buttons when I pair some buttons. That's OK, but I need to clear the button when I click the next one inside the same layout.