# Counter is not counting correctly

Tags: java, android

I have 8 pairs of buttons (16 total), with some terms from sqlite database. I need when user connect 8 pair (correct or wrong, it does not matter) to end the game, with some popup on the end. When I place counter<7 in my code, i need to connect 8 pairs plus to click once more on some buttons (17 clicks). If I enter counter<6, then I get my popup after 7 pair and one more click(15 click). I don't get that logic. So here's the code:

```
final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        private Button buttonClicked;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (counter < 7) {
                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.getBackground()
                      .setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

                if (buttonClicked == null) {
                    // first button is clicked
                    buttonClicked = button;

                    // only do stuff if buttons are in different layouts
                } else {
                    if (!button.getParent().equals(buttonClicked.getParent())) {
                        // second button is clicked

                        if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {

                            // second button is clicked and same tag but different button

                            Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            button.getBackground()
                                  .setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                            buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(
                                new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                            buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                            button.setEnabled(false);
                            buttonClicked = null;
                            score.setText("Poeni: " + brojPoenaSpojnice);
                            counter++;
                        } else {
                            counter++;
                            //reset LightingColorFilter first
                            button.setEnabled(false);
                            Toast.makeText(Spojnice.this, "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            buttonClicked = null;

                        }

                    } else {
                        //same button clicked show message or un toggle?

                        buttonClicked = button;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(Spojnice.this, Popup_spojnice.class);
                startActivity(i);
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask, 6500);
            }
        }

    };
```

Comment: what have u initialized counter with?

Comment: private int counter = 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you first check for the counter, and just then increment it, after connecting 7 pairs your counter will be 6 (still <7). Next time you increment the counter it will be 7, and your first condition will be false, but it will only be checked again in the next round.

To solve it, you should check the condition (`if (counter < 7)`) **after** incrementing the counter, and not before.

Comment: Thank you. [Can you check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960315/how-to-clear-color-of-a-button), it related to this class of mine?